# Does STL Map auto-initialize values?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does a class used as a value in a STL map need a default constructor in …?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346797/why-does-a-class-used-as-a-value-in-a-stl-map-need-a-default-constructor-in)

When I'm using a map, do values definitely get initialized to defaults or should I not rely on this?

For example, say I have the following code:

```
map<string, int> myMap;
cout << myMap["Hey"];
```

This will output "0" with my compiler.  Is this guaranteed behavior?  Is it possible that this wouldn't always initialize to 0?

Comment: Not a duplicate. The abovelinked question is about a primitive type in a struct used as a value for a map. This is about a primitive type being used _directly_ as the value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Quoth the standard:

> ISO/IEC 14882 §23.4.4.3
>
> `T& operator[](const key_type& x);`
>
> 1. *Effects:* If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.
> 2. *Requires:* `key_type` shall be `CopyConstructible` and `mapped_type` shall be `DefaultConstructible`.
> 3. *Returns:* A reference to the `mapped_type` corresponding to `x` in `*this`.
> 4. *Complexity:* logarithmic.

So, not only is it guaranteed, but evaluating `myMap["Hey"]` also causes the value 0 to be *inserted* into the map, if there was no entry for it before.

Comment: You'd also have to know that `int()==0`.

Answer (score 8):

It value constructs the value for a new key.  Take a look at [some documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/):

```
 A call to this function is equivalent to:
 insert(
    make_pair(x,T())
 );
```

This will translate into

```
 insert(make_pair("Key", int()));
```

So yes: your values will be zero at first.

Comment: That is not default construction. It is value construction. This is critically important; default-constructed `int`s have undefined values, while value-constructed `int`s have the value `0`

Comment: I keep mixing up both.  Thanks for the comment.  Edited the error away.

Comment: Correction: This is value initialization, not construction. Apparently. Point is it's not default construction :)

Comment: Covered in C++11 8.5p1-10,16 of the standard regarding value-initializing with () in case anyone is remotely interested (at least in my copy). Specifically, p7, which has a default condition of zero-initialialzation when value-initializing.