# C++ map do plus plus without initialization

Tags: c++

```
map<int, int> mp;
```

I can understand following code:

```
mp[1] = 1;
mp[2] = 2;
```

But how does this make sense?

```
mp[3]++;
```

without setting `mp[3] = n;` (n could be an integer).

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12889600/391161).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does STL Map auto-initialize values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889496/does-stl-map-auto-initialize-values)

Comment: You can also have a look at my solution below explaining example with global scopes.

Answer (score 7):

When `map`'s `operator[]` references an element that does not yet exist, it adds the element by value-initializing the entry.  For `int`, value-initializing means initializing to zero.  So `mp[3]++`, if the key `3` did not already exist, ends up setting the associated value to 1.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at -> "Inserts value_type(key, T()) if the key does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the document that managed by [SGI: MAP](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html#3)

The mp[3]++ will automatically call mp[3] and if you see the document, you can see when mp[X] is equal to (*((m.insert(value_type(k, data_type()))).first)).second.  That means data_type() is calling int().

In short, int() will be called as initial value. and int() is 0; Please refer the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int
main(int,char**)
{
    cout << int() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

PS. I found the right answer and reposted it. Thanks to [HisBlog](http://blog.purewell.biz/2007/02/stdmap.html)